# Is there any command to update UI immediately?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, dispatcher

I want to update a progress bar from running 1 to 100 with this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    progressBar1.Value = i;
}
```

But the result is, the UI freeze until looping finish.

I know `Dispatcher` can help, but I don't want to split function.

Is there any command to update UI immediately like..

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    progressBar1.Value = i;
    UpdateUINow();
}
```

Edit: I'm using WPF, and I use Thread.Sleep to simulate long running process.

In fact, I want any command liked `Application.DoEvents`. But I cannot find this command in WPF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Please* don't sleep in the UI thread. It will freeze your UI - it's a bad thing to do.

Either have a timer of some kind (use the right kind of timer and you should be able to get it to fire in your UI thread) or use a separate thread (either via `BackgroundWorker`, a new separate thread, or the `ThreadPool`) and make it call back to the UI thread to update it.

`Application.DoEvents` is a hacky workaround in WinForms, but the fact that you've mentioned a `Dispatcher` suggests you're using WPF - is that the case? The kind of timer you should use (if you want to use that solution) will depend on the UI framework you're using.

Comment: `Invoke(delegateInstance)` will do the job in WinForms.

Comment: +1 So glad someone was able to counter the ever-growing list of `DoEvents` recommendations while I ate my chicken fingers.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use a BackgroundWorker (a ThreadPool would be a bit overkill here but it technically could be used) and have it report progress.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a C# [BackgroundWorker](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) to update your UI.  This isn't working like you'd expect it to because the Thread.Sleep() is freezing your UI thread.

EDIT:  Tutorial that does a bit more what you want [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ditto on sleeping in the main (GUI) thread -- avoid it at all costs.  Although you don't want to Dispatcher, I'd still recommend trying (something like) this:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 100);
        _timer.Tick += ProgressUpdateThread;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ProgressUpdateThread( object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

See if [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) can help you out here.